# Hangman game - VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am making a hangman game for my son, in VB.net. I have made buttons for each letter, and i have also made a list of words. The problem I am encountering is when I am trying to print the guessed letters to the labels. I don´t know how to this. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

I will try to help you although you haven't show your code.

A simple approach is:

```
Private sWord As String 'Your word here
Dim arrayLetters As Array

arrayLetters = sWord.ToCharArray

For i = 0 To arrayLetters.Length - 1
    Dim lbl As New Label
    lbl.Text = "_"
    lbl.Tag = arrayLetters(i)
    lbl.AutoSize = True

    Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl) ' Assuming that you have added a FlowLayoutPanel in your form to handle your labels (AutoSizeMode=GrowAndShrink)
Next
```

Now you need a sub to check the if the user has pressed the right letter:

```
 Private Sub CheckLetter(ByVal letter As Char)
    For Each lbl As Label In FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls
        If lbl.Tag = letter Then
            lbl.Text = letter
        Else
            'Whatever you like if the user make a mistake
        End If
    Next
 End Sub
```

Now in the event that handles the buttons click

```
  CheckLetter("Here you put the corresponding letter")
```

Of course you can have one event to handle all the letters (or even use keyboard for input),add capital letters etc.
Show us your efforts